# chartjs Line chart: scale respect value on x-axis

Tags: chart.js

I am new on ChartJS.

I am using Line chart. My labels include value: [100,200,1000]

[image]

The distance between the labels is the same, and not depend on value of label.
My chart requires the distance between [200] label and [1000] label is 8 times longer than distance between [100] and [200] label.

Please help me with this stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Chart.js x labels are not number scales. However there is already a community extension (http://dima117.github.io/Chart.Scatter/) that does this. It is linked to in the documentation too (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-community-extensions).